# Is there anyway or work around to enjoy the dark mode feature of macOS Mojave without updating to it?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave

I have an old iMac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 now it has many default extensions and services disabled to boost up the OS experience.

Every time I upgrade to a major OS release macOS changes everything to default and installs unnecessary things. These unnecessary things slows down my mac. But I love the new dark mode in macOS Mojave. I want the new dark colored dock with white outline and everything dark included in the latest update.

But, I don't want to fully upgrade to macOS Mojave. So, is there anyway or work around to enjoy the dark mode feature of macOS Mojave without updating to it?

Comment: The core problem here is that you've made a bunch of tweaks, but not kept track of what they are! That makes updating difficult, not to mention full reinstalls, should you ever need to do them.

Take the time to go through and document all tweaks. This way, you'll be able to easily recreate your modifications after updating. It's also just a good way to keep track of the changes you've made to your machine, lest one of them is causing problems. I have everything collected in an easy shell script.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Yes you are absolutely right now I have even cleared all the shell logins and records so I can't even remember what shell commands or srcipt I ran before.

Comment: Well, you figured them out before, so you can do it again. You won't be able to stay on High Sierra forever, so you'll have to do this at some point anyway. Might as well start now.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I am thinking of buying an internal ssd with a case and install mojave on it cause my mac has HDD which is very slow so SSD might improve the performance

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Yummy, that script, is it online somewhere? Is it also Mojave-clean? Always interested in such things…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Briefly, no.

Why not install Mojave on a second drive (or just maintain a backup) so you can test things out with the new feature that shipped so you can revert as needed to your old system or data?

The framework and app updates to support this new feature are widely baked into the OS so you would need to have a poor excuse for dark mode by inverting the entire display using accessibility on High Sierra and lower.

Comment: And will it be safe to directly install mojave without updating to 10.13.6?

Comment: @Sayan With a good backup, anything is safe. I haven't seen anything explicitly listed in 10.13.5 or 10.13.6 that directly mitigate a problem going to Mojave so you might give it a go if you don't mind a little uncertainty and possibly slightly higher chance you'd restore things. .5 dropped in June and I believe there weren't lots of issues when people jumped to Mojave beta from 10.13.4 back then.

Comment: Depends on the intended usage. Dark environment in real life: Accessibility-Invert or DarkRoom (f.lux) are already great for that in old versions of the OS. Given the state of support for DarkMode in 3rd party apps, maybe even preferable. Using that in bright daylight? Just for the looks, if you prefer the aesthetics? Then Mojave is better, if not a must. But updating to that *now*? Brrr… I was cured of .0-itis long time ago ;) (Still, better theming-support would be nice. And upgrades are never safe 'in place'. Needing a backup means sth has gone wrong…)

Comment: So, I finally upgraded to Mojave and the system seems pretty fast but let's see for how long this change remains cause each and every time I upgrade to a new update the mac runs fast for the first few months and then it gradually slows down, don't know the reason behind this.

Answer (score -3):

> "Every time I upgrade to a major OS release macOS changes everything
>   to default and installs unnecessary things. These unnecessary things
>   slows down my mac."

Simply running the MacOS installer for a new version should not change any settings, defaults or options. (Maybe the Desktop image, but that's about it.) Unless you do a clean install, but that's nearly always unnecessary.

Secondly, merely having things installed on your disk (particularly OS-installed things) does not slow your Mac down.

*Hopefully, this answers your question by assuaging your worries about installing Mojave.*